# SqlDependency / Broker : Broken Notifications

Tags: service-broker, sqldependency

I begin with the broker notification system.
I use SqlDependency to notify data updates beetween application instances.
Overall, it works well. But sometimes, after a while, I don't receive no more notifications.
In SQL management activity monitor, processes keep *"BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR"* wait type.
Also, I notice this error in SQL Server 2008 R2 log : *"The query notification dialog on conversation handle closed due to the following error ... (-8470) Remote service has been dropped"*.
Is there a particular setting to avoid shutdown dialog notifications ?
Thanks in advance for your help.